# How to determine what type is used in a union?

Tags: c, types, unions

Is it possible to determine what type a union contain if there are several possible choices?

```
typedef union
{
    char     charArr[SIZE];
    int      intVal;
    float    floatVal;
} VALUE_TYPE;

VALUE_TYPE number;
number.intVal = 8;
```

How to know what the union contain here if the value was set from somewhere else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's right that you cannot do this kind of thing out of the box.

A common way to workaround this is that you can add a type along with your union. For instance, it could be :

```
enum { charArr_type, float_type, int_type } VALUE_TYPE;
typedef union
{
    char     charArr[SIZE];
    int      intVal;
    float    floatVal;
} VALUE;
struct my_value { 
   VALUE val,
   VALUE_TYPE val_type
}
```

After, you'll just have to update type when you assign your struct :

```
my_value number;
number.val.intVal = 8;
number.val.val_type = is_int
```

It's a common modern pattern when you need to have a common type capable of storing nearly anything.

For instance, you can found it everywhere in PHP source code. This is how they store different value types in the same object. See [this page](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch14_06.htm) for more detail.

Comment: yes but if he's trying to save memory, this will require to store an additional `enum` (integer?) for each `VALUE`. also, you can't enforce the user to store consistent values, that is one can easily write `my_value.val=10; my_value.val_type = is_charArr;` !

Comment: @vulkanino you can make a wrapper to set and get of this struct properly. In PHP, they use a lots of macro in order to protect their store-everything struct, and they store the type in a uchar.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot tell, the language has no facility for that.

You have to keep track of that yourself if you need that information.

Answer (score 0):

Using a union, it's up to you to keep track of whatever type you put into it and make sure that you retrieve the right type at the right time.

Don't use unions. Do you really have such memory issues that require you to save space?

Comment: Unions don’t address memory issues more so than they meet whatever constraints on arguments, functions, etc. are sometimes encountered when programming for embedded systems. I think you’re thinking of packed structs…